# FOR loop nested in WHILE in bash/shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, loops

I want to get proper output from FOR loop inside WHILE.
When i'm using command like this all is OK:

```
for i in `find ./ -name "*.processed" -mtime +0`; do echo "$i is COOL"; done; 

Output:
1.processed is COOL
2.processed is COOL ...
```

But, when i'm using this into bash/shell script, find put a list of all files with proper mask into variable (not one by one). Note, redirect "echo $i is COOL" to "wc -l" returns number of all files, damn. See following:
Entries of confif file like:

```
/export/home/.../ProcessedDumps;*.processed
```

All paths are full paths.

```
#!/bin/bash

CONF_FILE=$1
DAYS_OLD=0
counter=0
IFS=";"

if [ "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "-help" -o "$#" -ne "1" ]; then
    echo "Just archive your files easy!"
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` /path_to_conf/config.cfg" && echo "Exit!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "#########################"
date '+Date: %Y.%m.%d %T'
echo

while read LOG_DIR MASK
do
    cd $LOG_DIR
    echo "Dir changed to `pwd`"
    echo "Searching with mask \"$MASK\""
    for i in `find . -name "$MASK"`
    do
    echo "$i is COOL"
    echo "test"
    done
done < $CONF_FILE

echo
echo "Total archived files: $counter"

echo
date '+Date: %Y.%m.%d %T'

Output:
1.processed
2.processed
...
n.processed is COOL
test
```

Is bash provides nested loops with different kinds (inner FOR, outer WHILE). Have any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any problem with nested loops. It looks like the output of `find` isn't being split so you're only `for`ing over one thing. Is `IFS` set?

Comment: have you tried `find . -name $MASK`?

Comment: when you do a `cd` do you give absolute path or relative?

Comment: please paste content of CONF_FILE

Comment: I'm confused... Shouldn't `find ./ -name "*.processed -mtime +0"` have been `find ./ -name "*.processed" -mtime +0` ? (quotes only around file name...)

Comment: When using without quotes `find . -name $MASK` next output occurs:
    #########################
    Date: 2013.12.05 11:18:16
    
    Dir changed to /export/home/report/ReportsToBusiness/ProcessedDumps
    Searching with mask ""*.processed""
    
    Total archived files:   0
    
    Date: 2013.12.05 11:18:16</code>

Comment: `find . -name $MASK` doesn't search with regexp. Therefore, couldn't find anything that i need with MASK.

Comment: from what I recall, ``-name`` in ``find`` isn't supposed to use regex, for that there are other flags

Comment: please note that `*` is being expanded in `"*.processed"` before the `find` call

Comment: i can't agree, it's possible if enclose regexp in quotes like `find ./ -name "*.mp3"`

Comment: this is just a technicality "*.mp3" is a glob expression while ".*\.mp3" is the equivalent regular expression

Comment: actually. But anyway, this find works alone in terminal, but blow out in script. If i would use `full_path;"*.processed"` in config, i don't find anything cause the file with name *.processed is not exists on file system.

Comment: hobbs was right! I was rewrite IFS, so `find` expects `;` to split lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting `IFS` globally, which is interfering with your `for` loop, set it locally for the `read` in the while loop:

```
while IFS=';' read LOG_DIR MASK; do
    cd $LOG_DIR
    echo "Dir changed to `pwd`"
    echo "Searching with mask \"$MASK\""
    for i in `find . -name "$MASK"`
    do
        echo "$i is COOL"
        echo "test"
    done
done < $CONF_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be with the shell expansion, the follow excerpt worked as expected in my test here

```
echo logdir '"*.c"' | while read LOG_DIR MASK
do
  MASK=${MASK#'"'};
  MASK=${MASK%'"'};
  find -name "$MASK";
  for i in `find -name "$MASK"`; do
    echo "[$i]";
  done
done
```

**EDIT**: the IFS also has an important role if the filename has whitespaces, as noted by hobbs, in this case, one can use

```
echo logdir '"*.png"' | while read LOG_DIR MASK
do
  MASK=${MASK#'"'};
  MASK=${MASK%'"'};
  SAVEIFS=$IFS
  IFS='!'
  for i in `find -printf '%h/%f!' -name "$MASK"`; do
    ls -l "$i"
  done
  IFS=$SAVEIFS
done
```